# How do I take the ID item at the click of a button in an Angular table?

Tags: angular, typescript, button, angular-material

I have a table with a list of items and a button to show me the details:

HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="details">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Details</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
           <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="getDetails($event)">Details</button>
       </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
getDetails(event) {
  this.filter.type= "items2"
  this.filter.filterObject= event.value;
  this.commonService.searchClientiClick(this.filter);
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

The result of console.log(event.value) is UNDEFINED.

But when I use a dropdown-menu like this:

HTML

```
<p-dropdown [options]="DropDownItem"  filter="true"    (onChange)="onChangeItem($event)"  
            [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" >
</p-dropdown>
```

TS

```
onChangeItem(event) {
   this.filter.type= "items";
   this.filter.filterObject= event.value;
   this.commonService.searchClientiClick(this.filter);
}
```

It works! Takes the ID correctly.
Why? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I solved, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are different event types. Consider this:

When your `ClickEvent` object is sent to your first implementation, there is no values to consider on the event.

When the `ChangeEvent` object is passed, then there is a value as there is a value attribute on dropdown to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

you get a value on a Dropdown element because it has a value on selection or change event that is connected to the dropdown. But the Button itself will only pass the raw click-event. This is the reason why you have a "undefined" on the "event.value" key.

Hope this helps.

Just console the event like:

console.log(event);

Then you its easier to understand, what's happening.